# Different div 2 column layout

Tags: html, css, css-float

This is different than the simple 2 column layout.

I need to have this html:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="right">One</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div class="right">Two</div>
    <div class="right">Two</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div class="right">Two</div>
</div>
```

The div class menu has a static width, I need the divs inside it to go in a right column, and the normal divs to stay as they are.

Here's the CSS I got so far, but I cant seem to figure it out yet:

```
div.menu {
    width: 550px;
}
div.menu div {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
div.menu div.right {
    float: right;
}
```

The divs inside have random order, so I can't enclose them in a div and float that.

Here's a rough sketch of what the HTML code above should look like:

[alt text http://img102.imageshack.us/img102/4494/flytc3.jpg](http://img102.imageshack.us/img102/4494/flytc3.jpg)

Comment: Are you really stuck with that html?  If so then I think your only option is to do something very ugly.  Can you modify the structure with javascript or is that off-limits?

Comment: I was looking for a pure CSS solution, and yes I'm stuck with that HTML.

Comment: Is this programming related? Looks more like design to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
div.menu div {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
div.menu div.right {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to figure out what you are trying to achieve. Could you please create some basic sketch in MS Paint or something so we could help you?

**EDIT**: Maybe I don't understand something here, but this is exactly how it looks in my Chrome window (well, apart from the paddings).

Comment: I agree. I am going to guess that he needs to float both divs (to the right and left) and have some sort of clear'ing element after, if he can't change the div order or anything else.